# SplashScreen causes IO.IOException

Tags: c#

I am using System.Windows.SplashScreen to display a splash screen. There is a strange problem. If the image is in a different folder the application causes an IO.IOException (resurce not found).
I tried every build-type and the images have the exact the same properties.

```
public class DinSplashScreen
{
    private const int SPLASH_SCREEN_FADING_OUT_DURATION = 1000;

    private System.Windows.SplashScreen _splash;

    public DinSplashScreen()
    {
        // this works
        _splash = new System.Windows.SplashScreen(@"splash.jpg")

        // this crashes
        _splash = new System.Windows.SplashScreen(@"..\Images\splash.jpg");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows the splash
    /// </summary>
    public void Show()
    {
        if(_splash != null)
        {
             // here the exception occurs
            _splash.Show(true, true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: use it like this _splash = new System.Windows.SplashScreen(@"..\..\Images\splash.jpg");

Comment: post your folder structure. Make sure the image is really in that folder.

Comment: Any chance that the path *doesn't* point to an existing image? Why are you looking for an Image folder outside your application's folder?

Comment: Always use the full path.

Comment: You may want to use the various `Path` methods to make sure you have a fully-qualified path, possibly stored in a variable for troubleshooting. As it stands, your inline relative paths cannot be resolved for inspection.

Comment: Pay attention to the exception message, it is **resource** not found.  The SplashScreen class requires you to use a resource, not a file.

Comment: MSDN-Example uses a simple jpg. And with a jpg it works, if the jpg is in the same folder (strange!!!). It does not work with resources (i tried it) and it does not work with images in different folders. .NET-bug?

Answer (score 0):

Add your Image to resource file and then use it This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx) would be helpful to you for this you have to add resx file in to your project and then use it.

Comment: I added to the resource.resx as embedded resource. I tried the property "At compile time" also. But the same error occurs.